# class name warning for pylint type alias?

Tags: python, mypy, pylint, typing, type-alias

I'm using a [type alias](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#type-aliases) to make my code clearer:

```
MAGIC_TYPE = str

def f(x: Thing) -> MAGIC_TYPE
```

Pylint doesn't like the type alias and throws the following error:

`Class name "HEADING_TYPE" doesn't conform to '[A-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]+$' pattern [invalid-name] [3 times]`

I would prefer class names to still have name checks - so I don't want to get rid of these errors by changing the name, I'd prefer to be able to use uppercase for this type alias. Is there a fix?

The mypy doc seems to use title class (like classes classes)... but I sort of want to use the casing for a constant because this is not really a class as far as I'm concerned; it's a type.

Comment: Classes **are types**. And type annotations, like type aliases, generally follow the same naming conventions for classes for that very reason. So why not just sue standard conventions?

Comment: types are not always really classes however (e.g. `Optional`). I guess... I don't think it as a class, more like a constant so feel like I should say it's a constant by putting it in upper case. I don't really believe that type aliases being uppercase is a standard - so much as the choice in the documentation (it's not mentioned in [pep8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)) - there seems to be a tendency of people claiming the existence standards that don't exist. That said... maybe putting `Type` on the end is acceptable to distinguish it from a class that is actually implemented.

Comment: Look, you are doing something unconventional. There is no "official" convention about this, as in PEP8 (which is very old and not updated). But just look at **any** of the examples in the Python standard library or [PEP 483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/) ... You are free to use anything you wish to, but just know, it will look confusing to other python programmers

Comment: You're right that static types are often not really classes, but the naming convention for static type aliases is still the same as for standard classes. See the examples in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases).

Comment: @user2357112 Those are the docs I linked to in my question... but sure.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah.. I guess I sort of *want* it to look confusing or at least different. I think `Type` as a suffix in title case might be the way to go.

Comment: `Optional` isn't a type; it's an instance of `typing._SpecialForm`. Type hints can be arbitrary expressions, some of which evaluate to types.

Comment: Yeah. I mean it's "a thing you use in type annotation rather than a thing that you can instantiate". You can use a class as a type annotation, but not all type annotations are classes.

Comment: It's called a type hint. There are function annotations and variable annotations. PEP-563 deprecates the use of either for anything other than type hints.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the precision. Precise language is useful I suppose but doesn't seem to extend to the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) that use both terms "type hint" and "type annotation" as well and here's a [recent PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) talking about type annotations.

Comment: Yes, there is quite a bit in the documentation that should be reworded.